# Кодирование строки [0-9] в [0-9a-zA-Z] строку

Tags: c#

Идея такая: есть строка, полностью состоящая из символов цифр (0-9). Хочу закодировать ее в строку поменьше (и безопаснее) для передачи get параметром, используя символы (0-9a-zA-Z), и иметь возможность раскодировать.

Нашел решение

```
string Chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

string Base10To62(long N)
{
    string R = "";
    while (N != 0)
    {
        R += Chars[(int)(N % 62)];
        N /= 62;
    }
    return R;
}

long Base62To10(string N)
{
    long R = 0;
    int L = N.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        R += Chars.IndexOf(N[i]) * (long)Math.Pow(62, i);
    }
    return R;
}
```

но тут используется `long` вместо `string`, а у меня количество символов не фиксированное и легко может быть больше 100. В дальнейшем это решение мне нужно будет адаптировать на java, swift и php.

Comment: Что-то не могу понять это c++ или c#, скорее всего c# :) Метка вопроса правильная? У вас в вопросе base62, а не base64

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/923814/5909792 ?

Comment: лучше уж сжатие применить, gzip/deflate какой

Comment: Плохая идея. Почему? В ответе ниже пояснили, что экономия не существенная. Безопасности в этом случае нет и не будет - вы пытаетесь использовать Security through obscurity. `решение мне нужно будет адаптировать на java, swift и php` - если я правильно понял, это делается для сторонних разработчиков. Они вам за такой велосипед отдельное спасибо скажут. Хотите сжатие? Оно уже в http предусмотрено, посмотрите как включить.  А так, ради собственного развития - пробуйте.

Answer (score 1):

Прикол в том, что при переводе вы не сильно сократите строку.

На 100 символов:

`9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` - основание 10, 100 символов.

`2hqbczu2ow52bala8lgc3s5y9mm5tiy0vo9tke25466gfi6ax8gs22x7kuu8l1tdr` - основание 36, 65 символов.

`26:12:60:57:53:34:2:22:19:49:26:15:16:47:30:17:29:12:10:9:5:33:61:8:10:17:24:53:21:56:50:18:24:0:41:56:25:46:17:17:12:38:60:33:60:9:60:55:22:5:23:1:47:52:54:35` - основание 62, 56 символов.

Как видите, основание  62 не сильно укоротило строку, но зато добавило кучу новых символов.

При 100 различных символах в записи вы получите строку в 2 раза короче - 50 симв.

Наиболее оптимальное соотношение длины к кол-ву используемых различных символов  связано с числом Эйлера - 2,71... Наиболее "компактная" с-ма счисления имеет основание ***е***, а в вашем случае продуктивнее всего использовать основание 27 или 271. Но с оглядкой на символы и само программирование, удобнее 32 или 36 и 256, соответственно. 32 и 256 - т.к. это степени 2-ки, а 36 - кол-во символов [0-9a-z]. Если же комп оперирует тритами или работает на троичной логике, то 27 - идеально. ))

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999+base+10+to+base+36

Секюрность таким способом вы тоже не особо поднимете.

Просто возьмите готовый шифровальщик, если нужно зашифровать что-то, или же, если прет что-то повелосипедить, то придумайте сами какое-то взаимно однозначное соответствие 10 <-> 62.